# Can I determine at compile time whether --use_fast_math was set?

Tags: cuda, nvcc, fast-math

I'm writing some CUDA code, and I want it to behave differently based on whether or not `--use_fast_math` was set or not. And - I want to make that decision at compile time, not at run time.

It seems that NVCC does *not* add or change a preprocessor define when `--use_fast_math` is set. I checked this by comparing the output of:

```
nvcc -Xcompiler -dM -E -x cu -
```

with the output of

```
nvcc -Xcompiler -dM -E --use_fast_math -x cu -
```

and they're exactly the same; so that avenue seems to be blocked. Now, if the compiling user would invoke NVCC with `--use_fast_math -DUSING_FAST_MATH` then I could also detect that; but suppose it's library code and we can't impose these restrictions on the user.

Is there some other way for code  undergoing compilation to notice that `--use_fast_math` is on?

Note: "Noticing" can mean using preprocessor `#if` or `#ifdef` directives, using SFINAE, using compiler-builtin values or constexpr functions - whatever is available at compile time.

Comment: When you say "code undergoing compilation to notice" are you really referring to the preprocessor? How can code which is being compiled "notice" *anything*? (And I am sure the answer is no, this is effectively internal cicc code generation control, IIRC)

Comment: @talonmies: See edit. The preprocessor is what I was hoping to use initially, but it seems there's no definition being made I could latch on to. So maybe some other way.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is almost certainly no. The fast math functions are hardware instructions and they are substituted by code generation within the CUDA device code compiler. An example:

```
$ cat nonsense.cu

__global__ void kernel(float* in, float* out)
{
    int idx = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x;

    out[idx] = sqrtf(cosf(in[idx]));
}

$ nvcc -v -arch=sm_60 --keep -c --use_fast_math nonsense.cu 
#$ _SPACE_= 
#$ _CUDART_=cudart
#$ _HERE_=/opt/cuda-10.1/bin
#$ _THERE_=/opt/cuda-10.1/bin
#$ _TARGET_SIZE_=
#$ _TARGET_DIR_=
#$ _TARGET_DIR_=targets/x86_64-linux
#$ TOP=/opt/cuda-10.1/bin/..
#$ NVVMIR_LIBRARY_DIR=/opt/cuda-10.1/bin/../nvvm/libdevice
#$ LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/cuda-10.1/bin/../lib:/opt/cuda-10.1/lib64
#$ PATH=/opt/cuda-10.1/bin/../nvvm/bin:/opt/cuda-10.1/bin:/opt/miniconda3/bin:/opt/miniconda3/condabin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/opt/cuda-10.1/bin
#$ INCLUDES="-I/opt/cuda-10.1/bin/../targets/x86_64-linux/include"  
#$ LIBRARIES=  "-L/opt/cuda-10.1/bin/../targets/x86_64-linux/lib/stubs" "-L/opt/cuda-10.1/bin/../targets/x86_64-linux/lib"
#$ CUDAFE_FLAGS=
#$ PTXAS_FLAGS=
#$ gcc -std=c++14 -D__CUDA_ARCH__=600 -E -x c++  -DCUDA_DOUBLE_MATH_FUNCTIONS -D__CUDACC__ -D__NVCC__  "-I/opt/cuda-10.1/bin/../targets/x86_64-linux/include"    -D__CUDACC_VER_MAJOR__=10 -D__CUDACC_VER_MINOR__=1 -D__CUDACC_VER_BUILD__=105 -include "cuda_runtime.h" -m64 "nonsense.cu" > "nonsense.cpp1.ii" 
#$ cicc --c++14 --gnu_version=70400 --allow_managed   -arch compute_60 -m64 -ftz=1 -prec_div=0 -prec_sqrt=0 -fmad=1 -fast-math --gen_div_approx_ftz --include_file_name "nonsense.fatbin.c" -tused -nvvmir-library "/opt/cuda-10.1/bin/../nvvm/libdevice/libdevice.10.bc" --gen_module_id_file --module_id_file_name "nonsense.module_id" --orig_src_file_name "nonsense.cu" --gen_c_file_name "nonsense.cudafe1.c" --stub_file_name "nonsense.cudafe1.stub.c" --gen_device_file_name "nonsense.cudafe1.gpu"  "nonsense.cpp1.ii" -o "nonsense.ptx"
#$ ptxas -arch=sm_60 -m64  "nonsense.ptx"  -o "nonsense.sm_60.cubin" 
#$ fatbinary --create="nonsense.fatbin" -64 "--image=profile=sm_60,file=nonsense.sm_60.cubin" "--image=profile=compute_60,file=nonsense.ptx" --embedded-fatbin="nonsense.fatbin.c" 
#$ gcc -std=c++14 -E -x c++ -D__CUDACC__ -D__NVCC__  "-I/opt/cuda-10.1/bin/../targets/x86_64-linux/include"    -D__CUDACC_VER_MAJOR__=10 -D__CUDACC_VER_MINOR__=1 -D__CUDACC_VER_BUILD__=105 -include "cuda_runtime.h" -m64 "nonsense.cu" > "nonsense.cpp4.ii" 
#$ cudafe++ --c++14 --gnu_version=70400 --allow_managed  --m64 --parse_templates --gen_c_file_name "nonsense.cudafe1.cpp" --stub_file_name "nonsense.cudafe1.stub.c" --module_id_file_name "nonsense.module_id" "nonsense.cpp4.ii" 
#$ gcc -std=c++14 -D__CUDA_ARCH__=600 -c -x c++  -DCUDA_DOUBLE_MATH_FUNCTIONS "-I/opt/cuda-10.1/bin/../targets/x86_64-linux/include"   -m64 -o "nonsense.o" "nonsense.cudafe1.cpp" 

$ cat nonsense.ptx
//
// Generated by NVIDIA NVVM Compiler
//
// Compiler Build ID: CL-25769353
// Cuda compilation tools, release 10.1, V10.1.105
// Based on LLVM 3.4svn
//

.version 6.4
.target sm_60
.address_size 64

    // .globl   _Z6kernelPfS_

.visible .entry _Z6kernelPfS_(
    .param .u64 _Z6kernelPfS__param_0,
    .param .u64 _Z6kernelPfS__param_1
)
{
    .reg .f32   %f<4>;
    .reg .b32   %r<5>;
    .reg .b64   %rd<8>;


    ld.param.u64    %rd1, [_Z6kernelPfS__param_0];
    ld.param.u64    %rd2, [_Z6kernelPfS__param_1];
    cvta.to.global.u64  %rd3, %rd2;
    cvta.to.global.u64  %rd4, %rd1;
    mov.u32     %r1, %tid.x;
    mov.u32     %r2, %ctaid.x;
    mov.u32     %r3, %ntid.x;
    mad.lo.s32  %r4, %r3, %r2, %r1;
    mul.wide.s32    %rd5, %r4, 4;
    add.s64     %rd6, %rd4, %rd5;
    ld.global.f32   %f1, [%rd6];
    cos.approx.ftz.f32  %f2, %f1;
    sqrt.approx.ftz.f32     %f3, %f2;
    add.s64     %rd7, %rd3, %rd5;
    st.global.f32   [%rd7], %f3;
    ret;
}
```

You can see that there is no nvcc steered pre-processor magic, just arguments passed to the device compiler which has resulted in PTX code with the requisite instructions in place. This means that, in theory, you might be able to mess around with LLVM hacks to intercept or identify the bytecode you are looking for, but I very much doubt that is what you had in mind.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an ugly kludge instead of an answer:

Place something like the following in your code:

```
#ifndef I_ENABLED_FAST_MATH_REALLY_I_DID_PLEASE_BELIEVE_ME
#warning "Foo library is possibly being compiled without `--use_fast_math`. Please enable that switch, and define I_ENABLED_FAST_MATH_REALLY_I_DID_PLEASE_BELIEVE_ME, to avoid this message."
#endif
```

While this won't force your users to do what you want, it will be annoying enough to at least encourage them to do it. (Naturally they can simply disable the warning with the preprocessor definition.)